# what is the difference between objects.all() and objects.values()?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

what is the difference between objects.all() and objects.values() ?
i used like this

```
queryset = Consulting.objects.values() 
queryset = queryset.filter(consultant_id=consultant_id)
```

occurs some errors

but

```
queryset = Consulting.objects.all() 
queryset = queryset.filter(consultant_id=consultant_id)
```

is okay

i think these two return objects in my short knowledge

what is difference?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please write your code in a better way? It helps others when the question is well-formatted! :)

Comment: Have you read the Django documentation about these QuerySet methods?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#values
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `values()` function return dictionary. And the `filter` function does not exist in dictionary, so error occurs.

But `all()` function returns `QuerySet` class so `filter` function can be used.
The `filter` function is defined in the `QuerySet` class.